# Positioning a Widget in the end of the Row widget

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout

I'm just stuck here. I've tried everything but nothing works for me. All I want is to position the `Icon` on the right of my `Row`.

Note: I've tried setting all widget inside the row into a `Align` Widget and handle the position of that Align widget, but nothing worked. The code below is retrieving this:

[image]

This arrow, should go to the end of the `Row` widget.
Here is my Code:

```
Row(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start, //change here don't //worked
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
    children: <Widget>[
      Container(
        margin:
            EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0, top: 8.0, bottom: 8.0, right: 12.0),
        width: 15.0,
        height: 15.0,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: task.color, borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40.0)),
      ),
      Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(
            task.title,
            style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.black,
                fontSize: 19.0,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
          ),
          Text(
            'Duration: ${task.date}',
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 14.0),
          )
        ],
      ),
      Icon(Icons.navigate_next, color: Colors.black) // This Icon
    ],
  ),
```

Answer (score 77, accepted):

One solution is to use the [`Spacer`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Spacer-class.html) widget to fill up the space:

```
    Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start, //change here don't //worked
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                margin:
                    EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0, top: 8.0, bottom: 8.0, right: 12.0),
                width: 15.0,
                height: 15.0,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.red, borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40.0)),
              ),
              Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text(
                    "task.title",
                    style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.black,
                        fontSize: 19.0,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  ),
                  Text(
                    'Duration: ${somenum}',
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 14.0),
                  )
                ],
              ),
              new Spacer(), // I just added one line
              Icon(Icons.navigate_next, color: Colors.black) // This Icon
            ],
          ),
```

[image]

Here is what happens if you add it to the beginning of the Row.

[image]

Comment: If one uses Expanded or Flexible Widgets to size their widgets, the Spacer is not very useful because It has a flex:1 value by default.

Comment: @NoN You can change the flex size of the Spacer Widget. Spacer Widget is only useless with unbounded dimensions. There are other methods such as Wrap or Row space between

Answer (score 11):

**Solutions:**

1. Use `Spacer`:

   ```dart
   Row(
     children: <Widget>[
       Text('1'),
       Spacer(), // <-- Use 'Spacer'
       Text('2'),
     ],
   )
   ```
2. Use `mainAxisAlignment`:

   ```dart
   Row(
     mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween, // <-- spaceBetween
     children: <Widget>[
       Text('1'),
       Text('2'),
     ],
   )
   ```

---

**Output (same for both):**

[image]

Comment: `Spacer()` is the best thing I've learned today. I've been using overly complicated methods to accomplish this. Thanks

Comment: Thanks bro <3, u just save me. Before, i use Expanded() but it not work, but Spacer() saved time for me :D

Answer (score 10):

you can add `Spacer(),` above the widget you want to put at the end.

Answer (score 3):

Why don’t you use `ListTile` widget? Or wrapping `Column` with `Expanded`? I think that would be working.

Comment: ListTile is better in this problem. Also you can use Spacer() widget. more info : [link](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ListTile-class.html#material.ListTile.4)

Comment: ListTile worked great! This is the accepted answer in my heart.

Comment: You can use it, however keep in mind that it is too limited for some use-cases.